# Integral for the boundary of a polygon

Tags: calculus, geometry

I was reading a paper on the generalized Buffon's needle problem and I am a little confused about this statement. Could anyone please explain why this is true? Thank you in advance.

Consider a regular polygon $K$ and let $L(\phi)$ be the width of $K$ in direction $\phi $.

Then it is given that $$\int_0^{2\pi} L(\phi) \,d\phi= 2B$$

Where $B$ is the length of the boundary of $K$.

[Edit]

The statement is on page 3 of the pdf. Here is the link to the paper: http://tzamfirescu.tricube.de/TZamfirescu-140.pdf

Comment: I am confused too.Does the paper say anything about what they mean by "width of $K$ in direction $\phi$"?

Comment: @preferred_anon I have edited the question you can have a look at the paper.

Comment: For regular polygon, you can just compute the integral.  In general, it is a fairly standard result in integral geometry that the mean width $w$ of any compact shape in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\frac1\pi \mathcal{H}^1(\partial\operatorname{conv}S)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Do you know where I could find the proof of this fact for the 2-dimensional case?

Comment: See, e.g., [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295401).

Comment: This is true for any convex polygon. Let's say the $i^{th}$ side of a convex $n$-gon $K$ has length $\ell_i$ and making an angle $\theta_i$ to $x$-axis. If you othorgonal project $K$ to a line making an angle $\phi$ with $x$-axis.
The width of $K$ along that direction is the length of the "shadow". The key is
$$2L(\phi) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i |\cos(\theta_i - \phi)|$$
Integrate $\phi$ over $[0,2\pi]$ on both sides will give you that result.